# Python vscode method help when hovering

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

Using Python with vscode.
How can I get help on module methods when hovering?
Say this is the code:

```
g = df.groupby('key').value
g.mean()
```

I would like that hovering on `g.mean()` would return the same as `help(g.mean)`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Easy - press ctrl and hover above the function.
[image: Looks like this.]

Comment: This solution does not work for me, if `time` were a variable I created. Say, a pandas `DataFrame`.

Comment: It works the same way with the variables hidden under the help prompt